# How to change selected point styles in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

How to change style of selected point in Highcharts? I would like to give it different color filling inside other than white.

[image: Selected point]

```
 var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
 chart.series[0].data[1].select()
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/point-select/

Comment: I guess the following post answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193658/how-to-change-style-of-selected-point-in-highcharts

Comment: It works great for line chart but how about column chart?

Comment: you can checkout here,http://jsfiddle.net/cpxmzju3/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the states option for the marker.

```
marker: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        fillColor: 'red',
                        lineWidth: 0
                    },
                    select: {
                    color: 'red',
                        fillColor: 'green'
                }
                }
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cpxmzju3/10/